# Sqlite4java on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, sqlite, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to use my java project on Raspberry Pi. This code depends on sqlite4java which uses native implementations for many platforms including arm processors [link](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/downloads/list).

The problem is that java can't load required sqlite wrapper for arm processor. I was doing the follows:

1. Copied all version (tried one by one) of precompiled libraries (`libsqlite4java-linux-armv5te.so`, `libsqlite4java-linux-armv7a.so`, `libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so`) which I renamed to `libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so`.
2. Command `java -Djava.library.path=. -jar sqlite4java.jar -d` gives output:

   ```
   140213:092447.509 FINE [sqlite] Internal: loading library
   140213:092447.536 FINE [sqlite] Internal: java.library.path=.
   140213:092447.538 FINE [sqlite] Internal: sqlite4java.library.path=null
   140213:092447.541 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cwd=/home/pi/sqlite4java-282/.
   140213:092447.544 FINE [sqlite] Internal: default path=/home/pi/sqlite4java-282
   140213:092447.554 FINE [sqlite] Internal: forced path=null 
   140213:092447.558 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.name=linux; os=linux
   140213:092447.562 FINE [sqlite] Internal: os.arch=arm
   140213:092447.575 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-arm from /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so
   140213:092447.596 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-arm from /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   140213:092447.605 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-arm
   140213:092447.617 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-arm: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   140213:092447.622 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux
   140213:092447.627 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-linux in java.library.path
   140213:092447.638 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java
   140213:092447.642 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java in java.library.path
   140213:092447.645 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-arm-d
   140213:092447.660 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-arm-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-linux-arm-d in java.library.path
   140213:092447.676 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-linux-d
   140213:092447.680 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-linux-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-linux-d in java.library.path
   140213:092447.683 FINE [sqlite] Internal: trying to load sqlite4java-d
   140213:092447.699 FINE [sqlite] Internal: cannot load sqlite4java-d: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-d in java.library.path
   Error: cannot load SQLite
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: /home/pi/sqlite4java-282/libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
   at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
   at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromPath(Internal.java:337)
   at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:117)
   at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.main(SQLite.java:368)
   ```
3. Tried to set up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `/usr/lib`

On given path file exists. I had installed `sqlite3` and `libsqlite3-dev`. I'm using the latest raspbian distro on QEMU emulator:

```
$ uname -a
$ Linux raspberrypi 3.10.26+ #2 Fri Jan 17 22:13:59 EST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Any help will be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found solution. I had to build library file on Raspbian.
Here are steps:

1. Get sources from [here](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/source/checkout)
2. Get `sqlite_wrap.c` file from [here](https://raw.github.com/SpatialInteractive/sqlite4java-custom/master/custom/swig/sqlite_wrap.c)
3. Put `sqlite_wrap.c` to sources directory. You need `native`, `sqlite` directories and `sqlite_wrap.c` file there.
4. Create `RELEASE` file with content:

   ```
   #gcc
   gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -DARM -DARCH="ARM" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include/linux -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c ./sqlite/sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o
   gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -DARM -DARCH="ARM" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include/linux -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c sqlite_wrap.c -o sqlite_wrap.o
   gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -Di586 -DARCH="i586" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I./native -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include/linux -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c ./native/sqlite3_wrap_manual.c -o sqlite3_wrap_manual.o
   gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -Di586 -DARCH="i586" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I./native -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/include/linux -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c ./native/intarray.c -o intarray.o
   gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -Di586 -DARCH="i586" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -shared -mno-cygwin -Wl,-soname=libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so -o libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so sqlite3.o sqlite_wrap.o sqlite3_wrap_manual.o intarray.o
   ```
5. `chmod +x RELEASE` and run it `./RELEASE`.
6. `libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so` will be built, you need to copy it in proper path of your application.

Comment: I seem to be facing the same problem, but a bit unsure how to get the sources onto my PI and run your commands. Any chance you can upload your built .so file for download?

Comment: Compilation went fine. Update `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/` directory to your Java version, and remove `-mno-cygwin`. It took about 10 minutes in Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer. I've just updated the commands in OP's own answer for the year 2021 and OpenJDK 11:

Please note that you need to install OpenJDK (not only JRE) first.

```
gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -DARM -DARCH="ARM" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include/linux -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c ./sqlite/sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o
gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -DARM -DARCH="ARM" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include/linux -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c sqlite_wrap.c -o sqlite_wrap.o
gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -Di586 -DARCH="i586" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I./native -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include/linux -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c ./native/sqlite3_wrap_manual.c -o sqlite3_wrap_manual.o
gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -Di586 -DARCH="i586" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -I./sqlite -I./native -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include/linux -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/include -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT2 -DHAVE_READLINE=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DTEMP_STORE=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_OMIT_DEPRECATED -DSQLITE_OS_UNIX=1 -c ./native/intarray.c -o intarray.o
gcc -O2 -DNDEBUG -fpic -Di586 -DARCH="i586" -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LITTLE_ENDIAN -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -static-libgcc -shared -Wl,-soname=libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so -o libsqlite4java-linux-arm.so sqlite3.o sqlite_wrap.o sqlite3_wrap_manual.o intarray.o
```