# Use sqlite with Java on Raspberry pi

Tags: java, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I have created small code of sqlite database in java.

Below is the code for connection with database,

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

objConnection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/etc/javaData/Test.db");
```

In this code the exception thrown in second line for getConnection(). I am trying this code on Raspberry pi. How to fix the exceptionrelated to this

Exception

```
SQLITE addDeviceInfo()-[SQLITE] SQL Exception occured. RetryCount:1 (MAX Retry: 2) ErrorCode: 27154 Exception Message: Error opening connection Stack Trace: java.sql.SQLException: Error opening connection
  at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:140)
  at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:66)
  at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:21)
  at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
  at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
  at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
  at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
  at kmbt.DCA.SQLite.DCASQLiteUtility.getSQliteConnection(DCASQLiteUtility.java:152)
  at kmbt.DCA.SQLite.ManagedDeviceSetting.SQLite_ManagedDeviceSettingManager.addDeviceInfo(SQLite_ManagedDeviceSettingManager.java:981)
  at kmbt.DCA.DCAChildProcessMng.InitManagedDeviceInfo(DCAChildProcessMng.java:5726)
  at kmbt.DCA.DCAChildProcessMng.InitSQLite(DCAChildProcessMng.java:4387)
  at kmbt.DCA.DCAChildProcessMng.start(DCAChildProcessMng.java:365)
  at kmbt.DCA.DCAChildProcess.main(DCAChildProcess.java:23)
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error loading native library: /org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so
  at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:243)  at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:65)
  at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:53)
  at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:136)
  ... 14 more
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct and the exception thrown seems don't have nothing to do with some library's problem.
The only thing that sound me a little bit strange, is that you put your database in /etc folder. First of all it is not very correct, because the /etc folder is used to store config file and not data. In addition to this, maybe there could be some kind of issue with r/w folder's permissions. Try to move your database to your home directory or to other any directory owned by your user and not from root.

Hope this will be usefull for you.

**-- EDIT --**

Ok, the problem is that you have downloaded the wrong library:

```
Error loading native library: /org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so
```

You have to use the ARM build of the sqlite library. Try to take a look at this: 
[Error opening connection SQLite on Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665796/error-opening-connection-sqlite-on-raspberry-pi)
and this: [Sqlite4java on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750601/sqlite4java-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Database moved to another directory, now also it shows same exception

Comment: Could you add to your question the full stack trace given?

Comment: This is not whole stack trace, some part skipped from this.

Comment: Ok, can you post the complete one?

Comment: Complete exception posted

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you have downloaded the wrong library. You have to use the ARM build of the sqlite library. Try to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665796/error-opening-connection-sqlite-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: How to add this libsqlitejdbc.so file into sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar file

Comment: Well, I think that you have to re-build the library including the support for your system. Actually i never made something like this, so i cannot directly help you. Maybe you'll find usefull this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750601/sqlite4java-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: I have included this .so file into the .jar file and .jar file is replaced, now it doesn't show the error related to this getConnection(), but it doesn't process to next line after getConnection(), it goes directly into the finally block

Comment: After editing the jar file, It doesn't show this exception, but it throw exception but not catched in catch block, directly goes into finally block...

Comment: Can I see your try-catch block?

Comment: This code is written in try block and in catch block only exception catched

Comment: Now it gives another exception after adding the .so file,

Answer (score 1):

I also faced `java.lang.Exception: Error loading native library: /org/sqlite/native/Linux/arm/libsqlitejdbc.so`

Looking into `sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar` I found that `/org/sqlite/native/Linux/` contains no `arm` folder -> sqlite is not compiled for arm.

With these changes I've managed to build on the pi: https://bitbucket.org/kidmose/sqlite-jdbc/commits/cb7a7ef62c034938e8ecb737b148e5c80877c083

```
pi@raspberry ~/sqlite-jdbc $ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/
pi@raspberry ~/sqlite-jdbc $ chmod 755 ./amalgamation_version.sh
pi@raspberry ~/sqlite-jdbc $ make
```

Replacing the old jar with the newly built one solved my problem.

All credit goes to: https://pidome.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/java-goes-hard-on-the-raspberry-pi-so-does-pidome/